# Flutter - closing labels not shown

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I try to get the closing comments back, which disappear after I restarted VS Code. is a Here photo what I mean.
[image: Photo1]

No // behind the closing brackets. What I did was running `flutter packages get` inside the terminal becuase I need dependencies for this folder and after typing and restart the Editor, the comments wasnt there.

Inside the settings the Dart: Closing Labels is enabled..
[image]

I use the newest version of VScode and the Extention Flutter v3.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that setting the Closing Labels option via the GUI is not updating `settings.json` as it should. As a workaround, adding this key/value pair to that file and restarting VSCode worked for me:

```
"dart.closingLabels": true
```

On macOS, `settings.json` can be found at `~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/`

Answer (score 0):

File -> Preferences -> Settings -> search for Dart Closing Labels